# Render same panel at multiple occasions

Tags: primefaces

I am working with PrimeFaces and I want to know it rendering a panel multiple time within a same page is possible. For example, I have a panel like below:

```
<p:panel id="studentInfo">
  <p:commandButton id="viewFullProfile" ....
  <h:outputText value="Search" />
  <p:inputText id="search" ....
</p:panel>
```

I want this panel to in each tab of a p:tabView control.

```
<p:tabView id="studentProfile">
  <p:tab id="tabA">
     ..render "studentInfo" here...
  </p:tab>

  <p:tab id="tabB">
     ..render "studentInfo" here...
  </p:tab>

  <p:tab id="tabC">
     ..render "studentInfo" here...
  </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: Actually you want the same information in all tab OR refresh the `studentInfo` from all tabs?

Comment: same content, its like a header showing basic info which would remain same

Answer (score 0):

You will need one simple view like this :

**studentInfo.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition>
    <p:panel>
        #{item}
    </p:panel>
</ui:composition>
```

Note : I'm currently passing `#{item}` as a parameter that *could* be a student entity for example.

**Your view :**

```
<p:tabView id="studentProfile">
    <p:tab id="tabA">
        <ui:composition template="studentInfo.xhtml">
            <ui:param name="item" value="Student A" />
        </ui:composition>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab id="tabB">
        <ui:composition template="studentInfo.xhtml">
            <ui:param name="item" value="Student A" />
        </ui:composition>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab id="tabC">
        <ui:composition template="studentInfo.xhtml">
            <ui:param name="item" value="Student A" />
        </ui:composition>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: I think he need `<ui:include` !

Comment: @RongNK His question can be interpreted in 2 ways... will know soon which one is the one!

Comment: I tried using <ui:include but i got an illegalstateexception for a component inside "studentInfo" as it was rendered multiple times in same page.

Comment: ok so what will happen if there is a <p:commandButton id="studentProfile" /> inside the studentInfo.xhtml ??

Comment: @EddardStark all depend on what you want to do with it, should edit your question including what will be inside the studentProfile panel.

Comment: i tried using the template method and i got an error saying that it could not find component studentProfile

Comment: @EddardStark Did you create a new file containing the `ui:composition` ? Also have you used the proper path in `template=""` ?

Comment: yeah, i created a new file, and am using a proper path for template.

Comment: @EddardStark This error comes from an AJAX update from a `p:commandButton` ?

Comment: i found a solution to my problem, i used <ui:include src = "pagelink"><ui:param name="tab" value="tabName"/> and then i appended the param tab to every id of every component in side the page.